# A word to describe doing "good" things for "bad" reasons

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, someone helping their spouse find someone else to make divorce easier

Answer (score 4):

Something done with an **ulterior motive** perhaps fits what you mean.

Although it's not specifically about the morality of what is done (right/wrong), it's done with a, usually hidden, often selfish, real reason which differs from that which was professed.

> He got his wife membership of the country club with the ulterior motive that she might meet someone else to ease the guilt he felt at planning a divorce.

Comment: Your example sentence sort of falls apart in the middle.

Comment: @user888379 Thanks, I was editing on the fly as I wrote it and replaced the wrong word.

Comment: I was hoping for a word or a phrase for doing something apparently good for inherently selfish reasons. Not speaking to motive but to action

Answer (score 1):

**Self-serving**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/self-serving

> Working or acting for your own advantage:
>
> *Politicians are seen as corrupt and self-serving.*

Comment: This is too broad, 424, and includes doing obviously bad things.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Person 1: He is not really a bad man. He is even helping his spouse to find someone else.                                                                     
 Person 2: And for all we know he did that for a self-serving reason, that is, to make their divorce easier.                       
                                                                        Following the OP's scenario, would that not fit the context?

Comment: Many things would fit. OP asks for 'a word to describe doing "good" things for "bad" reasons'; self-serving is far broader than this, including all selfish acts / omissions (and 'bad' would obviously be ridiculously broad, while still true). I've got to interpret 'bad reasons' as immoral, selfish ones here, not 'injudicious' / 'unsound'.